# Can i play two video using canvas in html5

Tags: jquery-ui, html5-video, html5-canvas

[image]

can i play two video in sink using canvas and html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

studio.html5rocks.com/

There's an example here but it's a still frame when minified. The code is available there, so you can try it out, I imagine it can be done, but I've never seen it.